# JavaFX: Scroll a Pane with dynamic information(label, textfield, button)

Tags: javafx, scrollpane

How can I make that a Pane ( with elements inside) be Scrollable ?

In FXML file, i've put inside a ScrollPane, the Pane I want that it be Scrollable.
It's Correct? or i'm wrong?

ScrollPane.setContent(Pane);

Comment: You either put the pane in the scroll pane in FXML, **or** you do it in Java. But not both.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. Once you create the FXML file you simply need to display it as such:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("NAME_OF_FXML.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setTitle("ScrollPane Example");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

The FXML file should look like the follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="REFERENCE_TO_CONTROLLER">
   <children>
      <ScrollPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="320.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <content>
            <Pane prefHeight="382.0" prefWidth="386.0"> <!-- Add FXML id to your pane here -->
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Element 1" />
                  <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="170.0" text="Element 2" />
                  <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="352.0" text="Element 3" />
               </children>
            </Pane>
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Note that your pane must be larger than the scroll pane in order for the scrollbars to appear. The result should look like the following:

[image: Scrollpane screenshot]

If you want to dynamically add information to your pane, you can give the Pane an FXML id in your FXML file and then get a reference to it using your controller class. The controller class can be obtained from your FXML resource as follows:

```
FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("NAME_OF_FXML.fxml"));
screenController = myLoader.getController();
```

Comment: I've got ScrollPane(id="scrollpane") and Pane(id="mainpanel") on my FXML file. mainpanel inside the scrollpane.

I get data dynamicament from a database, and put it all inside the mainpanel.

For each value retrieved from DB, I add a label inside the main panel.
mainpanel.getchildren.add(label);

then, it's supposed that it should work....

but the Scrollbars don't move.

Comment: I agree that it should work. Can you post some code?